# Xamarin Android RunOnUiThread() not working after new OnCreate() call

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, bluetooth

I have a simple app on an android 6.0 API 23 smartphone. The app has a bluetooth barcode scanner attached. the Bluetooth class has a async methode which passes the input string.
Here is my main activity class:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TestOnCreate
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestOnCreate", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Bluetooth bluetooth = null;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            StartBluetooth();
        }

        private void StartBluetooth()
        {
            try
            {
                bluetooth = new Bluetooth(ProcessBluetoothInput);
                bluetooth.StartBluetooth("00:19:01:47:0E:70");

            }

            catch (System.Exception exc)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
        }

        public void ProcessBluetoothInput(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = text;
                });
            }

            catch (System.Exception exc)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the scanner is working and send valid information to the textView1.
Now when OnCreate() is called a second time (if the screen is rotated or the phone was on standby) the connection is lost. ProcessBluetoothInput(string text)
is still called but RunOnUiThread is not working.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the correct why to initialize my varables if OnCreate is called so often?

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: does your Bluetooth Service class has something to stop it like `StopBluetooth`? If so move your StartBluetooth to the OnResume method and make sure to stop it on the OnPause. This is because you might be trying to access the UIThread while the Activity is in background and that would lead you to some problems.

Comment: the code is exception free(in this case) | I will move the start/stop methodes to resume/pause since that will prevent future problems. But I cannot access the UIThread after my activity is resumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the Activity restarts due to orientation changes.

> ...an application can also prevent an Activity from being restarted when the orientation changes by setting ConfigurationChanges in the ActivityAttribute as follows:

```
ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
```

Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "TestOnCreate", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
   ~~~   
}
```

re: [Preventing Activity Restart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/#Preventing_Activity_Restart)

Comment: thanks. using ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape would also prevent reoriantation. But this would only be cosmetic since the underlaying problem ist stil there and could come back later.

Comment: @b.holz True, the root of the issue is you are not handling the Activity life cycle events...

Comment: so if OnDestroy and OnCreate are called I thought I could expect the same behaviour as the first time when OnCreate is called. why should I expect different behaviour?